# How to update large file in bucket without re-uploading in its entirety

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud

I have a large file stored in a bucket in gcs. When the user adds data to the file I want to update the file in my python script without reuploading the file in its entirety because that would take a very long time.

```
#here I retrieve from bucket
myblob =bucket.blob(name)
#here the user changes my blob by training it
myblob.train()
#now I want to update the old bob back into bucket with new blob without reuploading the entire thing
```

Comment: This is not possible, gcs does not allow incremental updates so you need to upload the complete file https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/objects#immutability

Comment: Are there any possible alternative methods I could look into?

Comment: Not with Cloud Storage (Object storage). But if you use other file storage, (persistent disk; filestore,...) yes you can.

Comment: Hi thanks for the recommendation. I'm quite new to google cloud so im wondering whether persistent disk would be able to store binary data?

Comment: Also is cloudsql possible with this? thanks again

Comment: Cloud SQL is a database; as well in some way you could store data is not an ideal way. PD is like a normal disk but for using this you may need a VM which implies an extra cost.

Comment: Hello wondering if i can use blob.compose([]) to update the file?

Comment: I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this  [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/objects#immutability) shared by @puteri in above comment

> Objects are immutable, which means that an uploaded object cannot
> change throughout its storage lifetime. you cannot make incremental
> changes to objects, such as append operations or truncate operations.

As an alternative workaround,you may consider the compose() method which  creates a new object whose contents are the concatenation of a given sequence of up to 32 source objects. The source objects must  reside all in the same bucket and use the same storage class. The source objects are unaffected by the compose operation and the resulting composite object does not change if its source objects are replaced or deleted.please refer this [document1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-compose) & [document2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composing-objects#storage_compose_object-python) for more information.